# fabricJS i-text with Roboto-Regular fontFamily render different in ubuntu and window

Tags: canvas, itext, fabricjs, non-english, latin

```
<html lang="en">
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
    <script>
        let json;
        let pageJSON;
        var canvas;
        var element;
        const STAGE_RESOURCE_BASE = "https://d33r26vb2a4c28.cloudfront.net/photoadking-test/";
        const HOST = { USER_UPLOADED_FONT: STAGE_RESOURCE_BASE }


        const json_data = {
            "requestData": {
                "json_data": {
                    "344516": {
                        "background_json": {
                            "background_image": "",
                            "background_color": ""
                        },
                        "sample_image": "",
                        "height": 800,
                        "width": 650,
                        "display_height": "800",
                        "display_width": "650",
                        "display_size_type": "px",
                        "user_template_category": "Flyer",
                        "is_featured": 0,
                        "is_portrait": 0,
                        "page_id": 344516,
                        "page_index": 1,
                        "canvasJSON": {
                            "objects": [
                                {
                                    "type": "i-text",
                                    "originX": "left",
                                    "originY": "top",
                                    "left": 136,
                                    "top": 360,
                                    "width": 417.94921875,
                                    "height": 118.65,
                                    "fill": "#000000",
                                    "stroke": "#ffffff",
                                    "strokeWidth": 0,
                                    "strokeDashArray": null,
                                    "strokeLineCap": "butt",
                                    "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
                                    "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
                                    "scaleX": 1,
                                    "scaleY": 1,
                                    "angle": 0,
                                    "flipX": false,
                                    "flipY": false,
                                    "opacity": 1,
                                    "shadow": {
                                        "color": "#000000",
                                        "blur": 0,
                                        "offsetX": 0,
                                        "offsetY": 0,
                                        "affectStroke": false
                                    },
                                    "visible": true,
                                    "clipTo": null,
                                    "backgroundColor": "",
                                    "fillRule": "nonzero",
                                    "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
                                    "transformMatrix": null,
                                    "skewX": 0,
                                    "skewY": 0,
                                    "text": "નમસ્તે Hello शहर",
                                    "fontSize": 60,
                                    "fontWeight": "",
                                    "fontFamily": "Roboto-Regular",
                                    "fontStyle": "",
                                    "lineHeight": 1.16,
                                    "textDecoration": "",
                                    "textAlign": "left",
                                    "textBackgroundColor": "",
                                    "charSpacing": 0,
                                    "excludeFromExport": false,
                                    "_controlsVisibility": {
                                        "tl": true,
                                        "tr": true,
                                        "br": true,
                                        "bl": true,
                                        "ml": false,
                                        "mt": false,
                                        "mr": false,
                                        "mb": false,
                                        "mtr": true
                                    },
                                    "isLocked": false,
                                    "styles": {
                                        "0": {
                                            "1": {}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "customSourceType": "text_json",
                                    "bg_image": "",
                                    "texture_image": "",
                                    "id": 795113,
                                    "index": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "overlayImage": ""
                        },
                        "threedObject": [],
                        "svg_json": [],
                        "tool_json": []
                    }
                },
                "totalCanvasObject": 1,
                "zoomLevel": 75,
                "my_design_id": "7wtwv41ef91417",


                "pages_sequence": [
                    344516
                ],

            }
        }

        json = json_data.requestData;
        pageStack = json_data.requestData.pages_sequence
        original_pageStack = [...pageStack]
        currentPage = pageStack[0];
        loadCanvas(currentPage).then(() => { })
        async function loadCanvas(currentPageId) {
            let promises = []
            let promiseLength
            fabric.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            pageJSON = json.json_data[currentPageId]
            if (pageJSON) {
                pageJSON.canvasJSON.overlayImage = '';
                element = document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas = new fabric.Canvas(element);
                canvas.setWidth(pageJSON.width);
                canvas.setHeight(pageJSON.height);


                if (pageJSON.canvasJSON.objects.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < pageJSON.canvasJSON.objects.length; i++) {
                        if (i == pageJSON.canvasJSON.objects.length - 1) {
                            loopAllFontFirst().then(async (result) => {
                                fabric.util.clearFabricFontCache();
                                canvas.loadFromJSON(pageJSON.canvasJSON, async () => {
                                    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        function loopAllFontFirst() {
            let promises = [];
            if (pageJSON.canvasJSON.objects) {
                pageJSON.canvasJSON.objects.forEach(element => {
                    if (element.type == 'i-text' || element.type == 'curved-text') {
                        promises.push(loadFontToDocument(element));
                    } else { promises.push([]) }
                });
            }
            if (promises.length > 0) {
                return new Promise(resolve => { Promise.all(promises).then((results) => { resolve(); }).catch((e) => { resolve(); }); });
            }
        }


        async function loadFontToDocument(element) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                if (element.font_path && element.font_path != '') {
                    if (element.font_path.split('/')[0] == 'user_uploaded_fonts') {
                        let font_path = element.font_path.replaceAll(' ', '%20')
                        var f = new FontFace(element.fontFamily, `url(${HOST.USER_UPLOADED_FONT + font_path})`);
                        f.load(null, 5000).then(function (loadedFace) {
                            document.fonts.add(loadedFace);
                            canvas.renderAll()
                            resolve(element)
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error, "error")
                        });
                    } else {
                        let local_font_path = element.font_path.replaceAll(' ', '\ ')
                        const LOCAL_URL = `"../../assets/fonts/pak/${element.font_path.split('/')[1]}"`
                        var f = new FontFace(element.fontFamily, `url(${LOCAL_URL})`);
                        f.load().then(function (loadedFace) {
                            document.fonts.add(loadedFace);
                            canvas.renderAll();
                            resolve(element)
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error, "error")
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    // const LOCAL_URL = '../../assets/fonts/pak/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
                    const LOCAL_URL = 'https://d3jmn01ri1fzgl.cloudfront.net/photoadking/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
                    var f = new FontFace(element.fontFamily, `url(${LOCAL_URL})`);//'url(./fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf)')
                    f.load().then(function (loadedFace) {
                        document.fonts.add(loadedFace);
                        canvas.renderAll();
                        resolve(element)
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error, "error")
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In the context of Fabric Canvas i-Text, we are encountering an issue where text with Roboto-Regular fontFamily rendering behaves differently on Windows and Linux systems for non-English languages. Specifically, when we try to display text in languages other than English, the fonts used for rendering vary between the two operating systems.

[Linux Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87uMz.png)

[windows output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVwwY.png)

my goal is to ensure uniform  text rendering across both Windows and Linux platforms, especially when dealing with non-English characters.